# How to correctly align a series of equalities when there is not enough space to place two sides on one row?

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, alignment

Writing an article in a two-column format, I stumbled upon a conundrum. In most situations, there is always enough space to write a series of equalities as one left-hand side followed by a list of equalities where the equal signs are all vertically aligned. For instance, consider the following sequence of equalities.
[image: Full-line equation]

What should be the alignment if both left- and right-hand sides cannot fit together on the same line? Instinctively, I would have a "phantom equal sign" in front of the left-hand side and align vertically all equals signs. This gives,
[image: Equations aligned on phantom equal sign]

I have been told it may not be readable enough as it looks (at first sight) like a list of unrelated equations, rather than a stream of equalities. Should the equal signs be instead aligned with the beginning of the first line? or with the first "symbol," for example under the integral sign like below?

[image]

In any case, my problem is not how to perform each alignment, rather I wonder which alignment should be used. All figures were produced with a simple `align*` environment.

Comment: The last equation looks the clearest to me. Indentation wouldn't really matter.

Comment: Do you mean the horizontal space from the left of the first line to the left of the equal signs does not matter? It has to be positive, unlike the second example, but any amount is acceptable?

Comment: _Do you mean the horizontal space from the left of the first line to the left of the equal signs does not matter?_ Yes, I meant that. I think in your screenshot (the last equation), the indentation is just right but would also be OK if you had to increase or decrease it. That's what I meant.

Comment: Please, add `\,` before the differential “d”: upright or italic (better the latter, but it's a different topic) it ***needs*** a thin space in front.

Comment: Alright, thank you both, it is noted.